# Git push commit without pushhing branch to remote i beforehand

Tags: git, github, push, commit, git-remote

Context:

```
git checkout -b testBranch (from master)
```

*DO CHANGES*

```
git add -A
```

(changes have been added)

```
git commit -m "This is a test commit"
git status
```

No commit shows up and if i push it says that already up to date.

So after some research i find out that this happens because there is no remote branch for my local branch and that i should do a :

```
git checkout -b testBranch
git push origin testBranch
```

I did this and it work but my question is what has changed that this is required. I have done this for the last year each day without needing to push the branch to remote (100% sure) .What did changed?

PS. I hope you guys understood what i meant, suggested edits are welcomed.

Comment: You probably pushed to a branch that already existed on the remote, like master.

Comment: you mean in the first or second scenario?

Comment: I mean for 'the last year'.

Comment: I know it sounds weird but it is true,i have maybe 100 branches that i have worked on and each time i only did the steps mentioned above.My collegue does the same steps but for him it works.